# Create new appointment on specific outlook calendar

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for Outlook VBA code that will create a new task on a specific outlook calendar???  For example, when I run the macro a new task opens.  When I click "save", it will add the task to my non-default calendar "Notes/Tasks/Reminders".

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the target calendar folder and then use the `Items.Add` method to create a new appointment there. Read more about all possible ways in the 
[How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/) article.

```
Dim appItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim items as Outlook.Items
Set items = yourCalendarFolder.Items
Set appItem = items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
```